# How to install gmp extension for php 7.2 using MAMP on OSX

Tags: php, composer-php, mamp, php-extension, php-gmp

> How to install gmp extension for php 7.2.1 using [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/) on OSX?

I'm trying to encrypt a token with php and this library([lcobucci/jwt](https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt)) using the Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm (ECDSA) with the P-256 curve and the SHA-256 hash algorithm.

**error when running php script:**

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Class 'Mdanter\Ecc\EccFactory' not found
```

I figured that I'm missing the `mdanter/ecc` dependicy package, so I tried running the following command.

**command running:**

```
composer require mdanter/ecc
```

**output:**

```
mdanter/ecc v0.5.0 requires ext-gmp * -> the requested PHP extension gmp is missing from your system
```

I've tried everything I could find researching this error and related to MAMP. But I couldn't solve this problem. **Is there anyone here who has experience in adding the gmp php extension to MAMP specificly and is willing to help me out?**

Note: I'm not a very experienced web developer, I mostly create iOS apps and I want to generate a token in php, so I can access the Apple Music Kit API resources.

Comment: Please someone has a response ? I tried everything but nothing is up to date ...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is how i did in `2020`

Download php from source https://github.com/php/php-src/releases pick the version which is matching with MAMP PHP version you have.

Copy the extension you want. Here we are copying gmp directory.

Paste it to /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.1/include/php/ext

(Make sure to move to your MAMP php version directory)

```
cd /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.1/include/php/ext/gmp
```

Then run phpize command

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.1/bin/phpize
```

Step 5:

```
./configure --with-php-config=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.1/bin/php-config
```

It outputs following

Then

```
make
```

Then

```
make install
```

Its installed now.

You can confirm it by

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.1/bin/php -i | grep gmp
```

**gmp support => enabled**

If you didn't see gmp support enabled, you may need to add following to php.ini.

This command will show you which php.ini file is used by MAMP php

/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.1/bin/php -i | grep "php.ini"

Add `extension=gmp.so`

Restart MAMP :)

Posted here with screenshots, https://mycodde.blogspot.com/2020/01/install-php-gmp-extension-in-mamp-2020.html

Comment: This should be the accepted answer imho. Thanks, it's the only solution that worked for me.

Comment: I wrote the answer. And It helped me after an Year when i had same question :)

Answer (score 16):

you have to build the gmp extension from the php source code.

you need Xcode and [homebrew](https://brew.sh/), to install compiler toolchain, gmp lib and `autoconf`:

```
brew install autoconf gmp
```

as my MAPP is shipped with php 7.2.8, I would use this php version as example, you could upgrade your MAPP installation or replace version related to 7.2.1. [Download](http://php.net/get/php-7.2.8.tar.bz2/from/a/mirror) and unpack php(7.2.8) source code to a dir, then config the build environment against your php installation and build the extension:

```
cd ext/gmp
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.8/bin/phpize
./configure --with-php-config=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.8/bin/php-config
make
make install
```

add the extension loading config to `php.ini` in `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.8/conf`:

```
extension=gmp.so
```

now this would work:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.8/bin/php composer.phar require mdanter/ecc
```

Comment: above 4 line commads not working for me , my GMP is installed in `/usr/local/Cellar/gmp/6.1.2_2` , this commands `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.8/bin/phpize
./configure --with-php-config=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.8/bin/php-config` not working :(

Comment: those commands(paths) are for MAMP installation, not homebrew.

Comment: @SaurabhMistry - you need to download a fresh version of 7.2.8 from the link in the description (http://php.net/get/php-7.2.8.tar.bz2/from/a/mirror) and then run the terminal commands from the ext/gmp folder in that fresh version.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the error `unable to locate gmp.h` while running the configure command

I had to use the `--with-gmp` tag in order to tell the good path to gmp.

```
./configure --with-php-config=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.34/bin/php-config --with-gmp=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gmp/6.2.1
```