# I cannot figure out how to install a PHP package for MAMP

Tags: php, ffmpeg, mamp, mamp-pro, ffmpeg-php

I am trying to install a PHP package called ffmpeg - I have installed it on my Mac using brew but not not able to get it working in MAMP Pro after adding it to the ini file like so `extension=ffmpeg.so`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install gmp extension for php 7.2 using MAMP on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50435455/how-to-install-gmp-extension-for-php-7-2-using-mamp-on-osx)

Comment: Thanks @CodeSpirit but unfortunately I cannot see ffmpeg in that list of extensions.

Comment: Your PHP configuration has a setting `extension_dir`. Basically you just have to copy your ffmpeg.so into that directory and than add `extension=ffmpeg.so` to your ini file.
Another question is, what exactly is the error?

Comment: Thanks, @CodeSpirit I have changed the syntax to my extension like so - `extension=/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg` but still no dice. Should I move the code from /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg to another location? The error is - Unable to load FFProbe relating to the FFMpeg class

Comment: Ok I got this wrong. As far as I know now there is no dedicated PHP extension for ffmpeg. Could it be that you are using [`php-ffmpeg`](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg) **library**? if so it will call ffmpeg with `shell_exec` so ffmpeg has to be installed on your system and at best be present in PATH. Also ffprobe is a seperate dependency which you have to install additionally.
Have you checked: https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg/issues/45

Comment: I think I have got it now. I just had to set up where the calls were coming from ie ```\FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create([
 'ffmpeg.binaries'  => '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg',
 'ffprobe.binaries' => '/usr/local/bin/ffprobe',
 'timeout'          => 3600,
 'ffmpeg.threads'   => 12,
]);```